# MySql While loop taking too long to query

Tags: php, mysql

just wondered if there was a a faster way of running this query? I have over 250K rows in my 'results' table. The code searches the table for all of the different types of race a trainer has run. It the looks at how many races that trainer has ran in the type of race. Then it looks at hoe many races he/she has won. Hope this is enough information. Thanks for looking.

```
echo "<div style='text-align:center;'>";
echo "<table id='main_table'>";  
echo "<tr ><td align = center colspan = 4>".$trainer."</td></tr>";  
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT 
DISTINCT RaceType AS racetype 
FROM results 
WHERE trainer = '$trainer' ORDER BY RaceType ASC");  //placing_numerical,
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ))         
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['racetype'];      
    echo "</td>";   
    echo "<td>";
    $result_horse = mysqli_query($db,"
    SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS result_run 
    FROM results 
    WHERE trainer = '$trainer' AND RaceType = '".$row['racetype']."'
    ");  
    $row_horse = mysqli_fetch_array( $result_horse );
    echo $row_horse['result_run'];  
    $a = $row_horse['result_run'];  
    echo "</td>";   
    echo "<td>";    
    $result_horse1 = mysqli_query($db,"
    SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS result_win 
    FROM results 
    WHERE trainer = '$trainer' AND RaceType = '".$row['racetype']."' AND placing_numerical = '1'
    ");  
    $row_horse1 = mysqli_fetch_array( $result_horse1 );
    echo $row_horse1['result_win'];
    $b = $row_horse1['result_win']; 
    echo "</td>";   
    echo "<td>";
    $percent = ($b / $a ) * 100;
    $percent = sprintf('%0.0f', $percent);
    echo $percent."%";
    echo "</td>";   
    echo "</tr>";
}   
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: look into `group by` with `having` statements. will save you from those tripple queries.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look at those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two suggestions you can check :-

1. For row_horse and row_horse1 , use "mysqli_fetch_assoc" instead of "mysqli_fetch_array" .
2. Try to write a single query taking all the three queries and it will save you more time what you are expecting .

Comment: Thanks for the info. How would i write them into one query?

Comment: First make the changes mentioned in (1) and let me know whether any change in execution time . Now , if you are expert in database , then it will be an easy task for you , otherwise you can hire somebody for that .

Comment: (1) has not made any change at all. I hope I haven't offended you in any way.

Comment: No offense here, in that case you need to re-write the query as we have discussed .